# I keep getting "error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp') at updateUI (app.js:66)"

Tags: api, asynchronous, error-handling

I am making a simple web app using async javascript
I am using api from the open weather map, everything works well except the updating ui
and I keep getting this error  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')    at updateUI (app.js:66)"
i think the problem is passing the data to the project data object beacause when i turned it to an array everything worked
this is my server side code
note : i required express, cors and boyparser

```
let entry = [];
projectData["entry"] = entry;
//post request
app.post('/add', function(request, response) {
  let data = request.body;
  console.log(data);
  let latestEntry = {
    temp: data.temp,
    date: data.date,
    content: data.content
  }
  entry.push(latestEntry);
  response.send(projectData);
});
```

this is my client side code that I wrote,  the updating ui function is not working properly and i am not getting an outout of the temperature however the result shows in the console

```
//

//Post function
const postData = async (url = '', data = {}) => {

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });

  try {
    const newData = await response.json();
    return newData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
}



//update UI function
const updateUI = async () => {
  const request = await fetch('/all');
  try {
    const allData = await request.json();
      document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = `Current temperature: ${allData[0].temp} degree celsius`;
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = `Today's date: ${allData[0].date} `;
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = `I feel: ${allData[0].content}`;

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
}
```

Comment: tell us about `allData`, Print it and show us the output

Comment: Object
content: ""
date: "2021-10-22T18:26:56.832Z"
temp: 15.3 
this is what i get when i print allData

Comment: Is it array or object ? Because in code (`allData[0].temp`), You tried to access  index `0` which mean `allData` is an array ...